# Web design for Legal pages: What are some things to keep in mind?

Tags: website-design, web-fonts

So I have been looking around but cannot find any good advice on how to go about designing a page for legal matters. These pages would clearly state Privacy Policy, Terms of Service, etc. **I think there is a huge challenge to designing these pages** because you cannot always make them flashy because, **from a legal standpoint, you want the reader to be  reading the documentation.**

I went and looked around and I found this question on UX Stackexchange but it does not truly answer my question.
[Design Requirements for ToS and Privacy Policy pages](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/34523/design-requirements-for-displaying-terms-and-conditions-privacy-policy)

**What are some things to keep in mind when designing legal pages?**

Specifically **I am hoping to find insight on what others have done to make the experience better.**

Comment: Actually, from a legal standpoint, you often do NOT want people reading them. So the first question is are you wanting to appease the end user, or the business? Sometimes they have conflicting desires when it comes to legalese.

Comment: @DA01 I see well definitely the company comes first - we want to secure ourselves but we'd like the experience as best as it could possibly be. Great point though.

Comment: I think most people don't read any of these legal documents.
maybe words could be replaced by illustrations somehow. I know I'm talking nonsense because its a formal document,but

Comment: Imho, whether the page is _terms_ or _copyright_ etc., it's either information or warnings/restrictions on rights. So it must bear the qualities these objects promote. The grid is not the same. Comments show that a business process is required to bridge the two worlds. The legal content must have attributes such as _authenticity_, _integrity_ and _legibility_ (visually). It operates by translating into legal terms an intent; it relies on trees of meanings which bind to textures of prescribed words' constructs. It is not an UX experience. **Documentation** is something else altogether.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the goal is to improve the end-user experience, then the key is that you improve the content more than anything. Ideally you'd:

- use plain language--not legalese
- reduce the amount of language
- offer a summary
- use good overall typography (an appropriate place to start: http://typographyforlawyers.com/ )
- make it possible to easily make an offline copy (make sure it prints well, offer a PDF download, etc)

Comment: I think the only concern with this I may have is that summarizing might leave sone things open to interpretation. Do you think this is a concern?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing the specifics of the content. It's a fair concern, though, and one that the copywriters and legal team should be aware of.

Comment: I would really really really strongly recommend taking out "offer a summary" unless it comes from Legal. In fact, *all* the copy should come from Legal. As a designer, you should be treating this copy, you'll pardon the phrase, like Greek. Don't alter a word, a comma, or a capital letter. If you have a query, ask Legal. You do NOT want to be the person who moved a comma and exposed the company to financial liability.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum I disagree with that. It likely *has* to be reviewed by legal, but legal, in general, tends to be horrific copywriters. If the legal document depends on exact capitalization and commas, then it's likely not easily readable by the and user anyways and should be rewritten by the copy team.

Comment: While there are certainly exceptions, in my experience, legal is rarely user-focused. They are almost always business-focused, which isn't always in the end-user's best interest.

Comment: I worked on financial documents for over 10 years, and I never *once* heard anyone say "This legalese is too complicated/hard to understand; can we rewrite it?" It was always "What comes down from Legal is sacrosanct. *You don't touch it.*" If your experience is otherwise (that anyone other than Legal is allowed to alter legal copy), I am frankly astonished.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum no, we've had the exact same experience. That is my point. Legal often acts like dictators and offer no consideration to the needs of the end-user. Legal tends to create bad user experiences.

Comment: That said, I have had (admittedly few) victories at times. For instance, at my current position, we've 'made friends' with a person on the legal team that has a deep appreciation for UX and has gone out of his way to revise long-outdated legal documents and 'rules' that have gotten in the way of UX here.

Comment: We're in agreement about the problem. I've just never found anyone on the legal end willing to take the end user into consideration that way. :)

Comment: @LaurenIpsum I think that's the situation I am in as well. I am trying to find a medium between what is best for the end-user without leaving ourselves exposed. I have talked to some legal teams and they are all very cautious. Needless to say, I think using good typography and making an offline copy available are both good points.

Comment: Accepting this answer because it answers my questions. If people have more advice, please feel free to post :)